# yelp search using Django

Tags: python, django, yelp

I am developing with yelp API, It works when I do the first time, but for the subsequent searches, it shows the same result. The following is my code

```
def yelp_query(keyword, location):
  headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % YELP_API_KEY}
  params = {'term': keyword, 'location': location}
  query = requests.get(YELP_SEARCH, headers=headers, params=params)
  return query.json()

def search_result(request):
  items = []
  query_item = request.GET.get('q')
  if query_item:
    items = yelp_query(keyword='query_item', location='London')
    return render(request, 'locator/search.html', {'results': items})
  return render(request, 'locator/search.html', {'results': items})
```

my HTML

```
<body>
 <h1>Search</h1>
 {% for biz in results.businesses %}
 {{biz.name}},
 {{biz.location.city}}<br>
 {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Now when I do my first search, for example, Italian food `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=Italian%20Food` yelp lists some result

`Fortnum & Mason, London
Team Man And Van, London
TopShop, London
Wickes Building Supplies, London
Sylvanian Families Shop, London, London
...`

when I do the next search for pizza `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=pizza` it displays the same result as above.

Can anyone suggest where I went wrong and How to improve my code.

Comment: Show us url patterns.

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^search/', views.search_result, name='search'),
]`

Comment: Try to change the second url(r'^$',views.search_result, name='search_result')

Comment: Getting the same result

Comment: You are getting building supplies results for an Italian Food query? That makes me think Yelp isn't understanding your query string. Even more so since you get the same results each time. Maybe try running the yelp query manually to make sure you have the request set up correctly.

Comment: Are your queries actually returning different results?  If you said Italian vs. Sushi do you still get the same?  My first thought is that nothing is wrong with code, but query is just returning the same results due to keyword similarity

Comment: I get the same result when I search for pizza and sushi. Whatever keyword I use first displays a set of result and any further search displays the same result.